# Issue with Bootstrap element not working as intended

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm learning Bootstrap and trying to recreate their example themes on their website. The one I am working on currently is:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/examples/pricing/

My pricing cards are not working the same way. I've included the code below.

Is anyone able to explain why my price cards are getting individually wider while the screen size is changed, whereas the Bootstrap versions stay the same (in terms of width and height).

Thank you!

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
        <div class="card-deck mb-3 text-center">
      <!--Price Section-->
    
      <div class="card mb-4 shadow-sm">
    
        <div class="card-header">
            <h4 class="my-0 font-weight-normal">Free</h4>
        </div>
    
        <div class="card-body">
    
            <div class="card-title">
                <h1>$0 <small class="text-muted">/ mo</small></h1>
            </div>
            <ul class="card-text list-unstyled mt-3 mb-4">
                <li>10 users included</li>
                <li>2 GB of storage</li>
                <li>Email Support</li>
                <li>Help Center Access</li>
            </ul>
    
        
            <button type="button" class='btn btn-lg btn-block btn-outline- 
       primary'>Sign Up</button>
        </div>
    
        </div>
    
        <!--Price End-->
     
    
        <!--Price Two-->
        <div class="card mb-4 shadow-sm">
    
            <div class="card-header">
                    <h4 class="my-0 font-weight-normal">Free</h4>
                </div>
        
            <div class="card-body">
        
                <div class="card-title">
                    <h1>$15 <small class="text-muted">/ mo</small></h1>
                </div>
                <ul class="card-text list-unstyled mt-3 mb-4">
                    <li>10 users included</li>
                    <li>2 GB of storage</li>
                    <li>Email Support</li>
                    <li>Help Center Access</li>
                </ul>
        
          
                <button type="button" class='btn btn-lg btn-block btn- 
       primary'>Sign Up</button>
            </div>
        
        </div>
        
       <!--Price End-->
    
    
       <!--Price Three-->
       <div class="card mb-4 shadow-sm">
    
            <div class="card-header">
                    <h4 class="my-0 font-weight-normal">Free</h4>
                </div>
        
            <div class="card-body">
        
                <div class="card-title">
                    <h1>$29 <small class="text-muted">/ mo</small></h1>
                </div>
                <ul class="card-text list-unstyled mt-3 mb-4">
                    <li>10 users included</li>
                    <li>2 GB of storage</li>
                    <li>Email Support</li>
                    <li>Help Center Access</li>
                </ul>
        
                      <button type="button" class='btn btn-lg btn-block btn- 
      primary'>Sign Up</button>
            </div>
        
       </div>
       <!--Price End-->
       </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just button class not apply properly. Try this solution

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="card-deck mb-3 text-center">
      <!--Price Section-->

      <div class="card mb-4 shadow-sm">
        <div class="card-header">
          <h4 class="my-0 font-weight-normal">Free</h4>
        </div>

        <div class="card-body">
          <div class="card-title">
            <h1>$0 <small class="text-muted">/ mo</small></h1>
          </div>
          <ul class="card-text list-unstyled mt-3 mb-4">
            <li>10 users included</li>
            <li>2 GB of storage</li>
            <li>Email Support</li>
            <li>Help Center Access</li>
          </ul>
          <button class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-block">Sign Up</button>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!--Price End-->

      <!--Price Two-->
      <div class="card mb-4 shadow-sm">
        <div class="card-header">
          <h4 class="my-0 font-weight-normal">Free</h4>
        </div>

        <div class="card-body">
          <div class="card-title">
            <h1>$15 <small class="text-muted">/ mo</small></h1>
          </div>
          <ul class="card-text list-unstyled mt-3 mb-4">
            <li>10 users included</li>
            <li>2 GB of storage</li>
            <li>Email Support</li>
            <li>Help Center Access</li>
          </ul>

          <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Sign Up</button>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!--Price End-->

      <!--Price Three-->
      <div class="card mb-4 shadow-sm">
        <div class="card-header">
          <h4 class="my-0 font-weight-normal">Free</h4>
        </div>

        <div class="card-body">
          <div class="card-title">
            <h1>$29 <small class="text-muted">/ mo</small></h1>
          </div>
          <ul class="card-text list-unstyled mt-3 mb-4">
            <li>10 users included</li>
            <li>2 GB of storage</li>
            <li>Email Support</li>
            <li>Help Center Access</li>
          </ul>

          <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Sign Up</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--Price End-->
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Works, seems I had the wrong CDN linked. I wonder why that would cause this issue...